# import fs module: uncaught typeerror

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, fs

I am trying to use node module in my typescript code, however I get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`
I have looked the previous posts on stackflow and tried updating my tscofig.json file.
I have tried importing it as:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
const fs = require('fs');
```

However, both results in the runtime error.
Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
　　　　　"target": "es5",  
  　　　　"module": "ES6",  
  　　　　"rootDir": "./src",
 　　　　 "outDir": "./dist" 
 　　　}
}
```

Would be great it someone can guide me towards the cause of the error and possible solutions。

P.S. I have tried reinstalling node modules using `npm install --save @types/node`

Comment: Can you specify which typescript version you are using?

Comment: I am using 4.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Change tsconfig.json like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "rootDir": "./src",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```